# trying to set halignment to label text in a python file

Tags: python, kivy

i am trying to set halign for label text created in python file. the alignment not working as i want. after applying the setting below that i commented out, it aligns the text in the label, but the text didnt use the whole width of the label. like it reduced the label width or text compressed and text that's suppose to be one line now take 3 lines. what am i doing wrong?
python file

```
    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        bxx = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1, 30))
        lbx1 = Label()
        lbx1.size_hint_x = .8
        lbx2 = Label(text="Product", font_size=20, color=(0,0,1), size_hint_x=2)

        lbx3 = Label(text="Quantity", font_size=20, color=(0, 0, 1))
        #lbx3.text_size = lbx3.size
        #lbx3.halign = "left"
        #lbx3.valign = "middle"
        lbx4 = Label(text="Price", font_size=20, color=(0, 0, 1))
        #lbx4.text_size = lbx4.size
        #lbx4.halign = "right"
        #lbx4.valign = "middle"
        lbx5 = Label()
        lbx5.size_hint_x=.8
        bxx.add_widget(lbx1)
        bxx.add_widget(lbx2)
        bxx.add_widget(lbx3)
        bxx.add_widget(lbx4)
        bxx.add_widget(lbx5)
        self.ids.rcp.add_widget(bxx)

        for i in range(len(wk.Forsales.slpr)):
            blt = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1,30))
            lt1 = Label()
            lt1.size_hint_x= .8
            lt2 = Label(text=(wk.Forsales.slpr[i]), font_size=12, color=(0, 0, 1), 
            size_hint_x=2)
            #lt2.text_size = lt2.size
            #lt2.halign = "left"
            #lt2.valign = "middle"
            lt3 = Label(text=str(wk.Forsales.slqtyn[i]) + " " + str(wk.Forsales.slqtyw[i]), 
            font_size=12, color=(0, 0, 1))
            #lt3.text_size = lt3.size
            #lt3.halign = "left"
            #lt3.valign = "middle"
            lt4 = Label(text="{:,.2f}".format(wk.Forsales.slp[i]), font_size=12, color=(0, 0, 
            1))
            #lt4.text_size = lt4.size
            #lt4.halign = "right"
            #lt4.valign = "middle"
            lt5 = Label()
            lt5.size_hint_x=.8
            blt.add_widget(lt1)
            blt.add_widget(lt2)
            blt.add_widget(lt3)
            blt.add_widget(lt4)
            blt.add_widget(lt5)
            self.ids.rcp.add_widget(blt)

        bxb = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1, 30))
        lxb1 = Label()
        lxb1.size_hint_x=.8
        lxb2 = Label(text="", font_size=20, color=(0, 0, 1), size_hint_x=2)
        lxb3 = Label(text="Total", font_size=20, color=(0, 0, 1))
        lxb4 = Label(text="{:,.2f}".format(sum(wk.Forsales.slp)), font_size=20, color=(0, 
            0, 1)) 
        #lxb4.text_size = lxb4.size
        #lxb4.halign = "right"
        #lxb4.valign = "middle"
        lxb5 = Label()
        lxb5.size_hint_x=.8
        bxb.add_widget(lxb1)
        bxb.add_widget(lxb2)
        bxb.add_widget(lxb3)
        bxb.add_widget(lxb4)
        bxb.add_widget(lxb5)
        self.ids.rcp.add_widget(bxb)

        bbb = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1, 30))
        self.ids.rcp.add_widget(bbb)

        bbx = BoxLayout(orientation="horizontal", size_hint=(1, None), size=(1, 30))
        lx1 = Label()
        lx1.size_hint_x= .8
        lx2 = Label(text="Seller's Signature", font_size=15, color=(0, 0, 1), size_hint_x=2)
        lx3 = Label(text="", font_size=20, color=(0, 0, 1))
        lx4 = Label(text="Buyer's Signature", font_size=15, color=(0, 0, 1))

        lx5 = Label()
        lx5.size_hint_x=.8
        bbx.add_widget(lx1)
        bbx.add_widget(lx2)
        bbx.add_widget(lx3)
        bbx.add_widget(lx4)
        bbx.add_widget(lx5)
        self.ids.rcp.add_widget(bbx)
```

Comment: You need to modify the `text_size` property of that `Label` (i.e. bind to some other value like width etc. which can conveniently done using `kvlang` or in python, using custom callback function).

Comment: @ApuCoder please show me an example of a callback for the label width. I have been trying to do that bit it is not working. And I forgot to mention that the labels goes into a scrollview layout. Please help me out man

Comment: @John Anderson I need your help

Comment: Try posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).